# Unable to composer install/require from a private GitLab repo (namespace)

Tags: git, composer-php, gitlab

I am having problems installing a private composer library from a private GitLab repo.

My private library which I want to use has this in it's `composer.json` and is stored on my GitLab:

```
{
    "name": "zlatan/app-client",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "description": "Client in PHP",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Zlatan Omerovic",
            "email": "gmail@com.zlatan"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "symfony/http-client": "^4.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "AppClient\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

My Git path to my library is: `/namespace/project/app-client.git`, i.e.

```
git@zlatan.gitlab.com:namespace/project/app-client.git
```

And now I'd like to use that library which I have named `zlatan/app-client`, in another `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "zlatan/composer",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Zlatan Omerovic",
            "email": "gmail@com.zlatan"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "zlatan/app-client": "master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "git@zlatan.gitlab.com:namespace/project/app-client.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, when I run `composer install`, I always get this output:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package zlatan/app-client could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

My first and only guess is that these GitLab namespaces / prefixes in the URI are making a problem?

Is it possible to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `dev-master` to reference to your master branch.

Using `master` will instruct Composer to search for a tag named `master` and if that does not exist, it will fail.

Additionally, you can try adding `"minimum-stability": "dev"` to your `composer.json` to make sure development versions of packages can be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use proxy or vpn app when you want to use composer install command

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).